# Trying to install 'openxlsx' library in conda R environment

Tags: r, conda, install.packages, openxlsx

I am trying to install 'openxlsx' library in conda R. I used 'conda install -c r r-openxlsx' command to install but it keeps showing following error:
[image: ERROR]

These are my channels:
[image: channel list]

I tried adding a channel r as well, but it is still showing same error. How can I install the package?

I tried 'conda install -c r r-openxlsx' in the terminal as well as 'install.packages("openxlsx", repos = "https://cran.r-project.org")' and 'install.packages("openxlsx")' in the conda R environment, but none is working.

Comment: This looks like a networking issue, why have you hidden the web-url. Have you modified somehow where conda is looking for channels?

Comment: Also, avoid posting screenshots of console output. Copy/paste the actual error message into your question, as it is much more readable and accessible

Comment: I can't share the url because it belongs to a corporate server. I didn't modify anything as far as I know.
Sure, I'll copy and paste the output from now. Should I share any other information that can be useful to pin point the error?

Comment: Use Conda Forge for R.